# Export a custom Mysql database product catalog to Wordpress

Tags: database, export

I have a custom product catalog database, and I want to migrate it to WordPress.
are there any tools for that? or I have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your custom product catalog is written by you, then you have to do it manually, you can write a script to automate that product if your catalog database is big.
Also, there is a plugin to do that you can give a try but this solution is not error-proof, a wrong step will destroy your database. So before proceeding please take a backup of your WP database.

[Paid Solution](https://toolset.com/documentation/programmer-reference/how-to-import-a-database-into-wordpress/)